# Is it possible to set a default precision for the Unix dc calculator? Is there a config file for it?

Tags: unix, dc

You can set the precision after invoking dc with the 'k' command, which pops a number off the stack and uses it to set the precision. But I always want a precision of three digits after the decimal by default. Is there a way to set a default precision in dc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I've done to achieve this is create a file in your home directory called `.dcinit` with the commands you want executed every time, e.g.

```
bash-3.2$ cat .dcinit
5 k
bash-3.2$
```

Then define an alias in your startup config file for `dc` that loads the startup file and then reads from stdin:

```
bash-3.2$ alias dc="dc -f ~/.dcinit -"
```

You should be able to use it as normal interactively but it will first load your `.dcinit`:

```
bash-3.2$ dc
4 5 / p 
.80000
```

If you need to run it on a file of `dc` commands, you'll have to disable the alias or run it explicitly from `/usr/bin/dc` or whereever.

Comment: You can just use `~/.dcrc` which it already executes automatically per the man page.

Comment: @nyuszika7h, unfortunately, `.dcrc` isn't universal.  It's not available on my system (OS X), not in the man page (`man -t dc | grep dcrc` returns nothing.)  Nor will you find it in all `dc` man pages on the web, e.g. [FreeBSD General Commands Manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dc&sektion=1) which is why I had to come up with my work-around.